# Running out of disk space, MySQL (VM azure)

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I created replication in Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine .

I'm using MySQL and working with sql workbench (windows).

yesterday I discovered that my 250 GB storage are full and replication stopped.

this log wrote,

```
 Timestamp, Thread, Type, Details
2015-07-29 23:26:44, 1672, Warning, Disk is full writing '.\database123-relay-bin.000164' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device). Waiting for someone to free space...
```

and I created another 250 GB external storage.

I have 2 Q :

1. how can I create queries and use data within two difference storage ?
2. is it the right thing to do? to create another storage or there is a way to create flexible storage

   ?

that i found is this : http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/07/running-out-of-disk-space-on-mysql-partition-a-quick-rescue/

but it not help , need help and Guidance

this is another option that i found :
[how to extend C drive size of Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351437/how-to-extend-c-drive-size-of-azure-vm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data disks for storing application data from your Azure VMs. The largest data disk size available is 1TB. If you require more space, you can stripe more than one data disk together. Avoid using the OS disk for storing application data because you will run into this issue of limited space. Also avoid using the temporary disk for storing application data as it is not persistent. You cannot extend the OS disk size, but if you use data disks, you can start with a smaller data disk and increase its size as your application grows.

Learn more about Azure disks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/Dn790303.aspx